# Java beans performance with object inside object

Tags: java

I am developing a bean class which has multi face properties (name has first name, last name and middle name). The object is going to be used to create an xml file. Please compare my two methods to incorporate the same in my application.

Method 1:

```
public class SampleVO {
String firstName;
String middleName;
String lastName;
// getters and setters
}
```

Method 2:

```
//Main object
public class SampleVO1 {
NameVO name = new NameVO();
// getters and setters
}
//Name object
public class NameVO {
    String firstName;
    String middleName;
    String lastName;
    // getters and setters
}
```

Note: Above is just a sample. The requirement is to group a set of properties. In Which way of the above performance/code standards will be good?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a performance perspective both approaches are comparable. Yes, method 2 will use some additional memory and require a few more instructions for instantiating your `NameVO`, but unless you're dealing with millions of objects, I would not worry too much about that.

From a coding standards perspective, method 2 is superior over method 1. In general, composite values (such as names) deserve their own object.

First of all, it allows you to add additional methods in your `NameVO`, such as the likely `String getFullName()`, which handles the possibility of having `null` as a middleName. This also gives you the flexibility to change the contents of a `NameVO` later on, for example by adding initials, salutations, etc.

Secondly, it gives you the option to reuse `NameVO` in other contexts. For example, you could have a `Customer` object with a `name` field, and a `Supplier` with a `name` field, etc.

Thirdly, if your code uses validation, you can decouple the validation of the contents of a name from the validation of the existence of a name.

Furthermore, by adding an `equals` and `hashCode`, you also gain the possibility to store your objects in a `Map`, indexed by `NameVO`.

As an aside, I would even go so far as to suggest a slightly modified version of your method 2:

```
public class SampleVO {
    NameVO name;
    // getters and setters
}

//Name object
public class NameVO {
    final String firstName;
    final String middleName;
    final String lastName;

    public NameVO(String firstName, String middleName, String lastName) {
      // assignments
    }

    // getters 
}
```

This effectively makes your `NameVO` immutable, making it more suitable for use as a key in a `Map`. It also makes it safer to pass `NameVO` objects around without having to fear side effects.

Comment: Ah, I might have misunderstood the question. I thought `SampleVO` also was an independent name object. In that case I have to perfectly agree with you. You are completely right about immutability and using as key in a `Map`.

Comment: As for the key-in-the map, it may not be obvious that it also needs an override to the `hashCode` and `equals` method.